# Would constructing an "semi-realistic/semi-super" mecha be plausible?

Tags: weapons, virtual-reality

For two years, I've been interested(obsessed) with mecha, aka: giant robots, especially "super robots".

Would it be possible for somebody to create a humanoid, but reasonably sized mecha that combines functionalities from both super and real robots? For example: combining both exotic and conventional technology, such as antimatter and kinetic weaponry, and using nanotechnology to emulate the "transformations" of classic super robots. They can also be some additions, such as:

A neural interface, in either a "Matrix-style plugin" or a "brain-in-a-vat" variant, which has  person's brain installed into the robot, and from there, it can be "piloted" by the brain's neural impulses. The latter would be especially useful(if the it's designed for it)since the system would allow the mecha(and its "pilot") to enter a Matroishka Brain and access its programs, such as its virtual reality constructs.

As for "combining", the robot should be able to use its nanomachines to interface with a separate vehicle, such as another mecha. If it combines with a bioship(since it's made up of living components), then it's possible for the mecha to gain access to the ship's nervous system and primary functions(weapons and propulsion systems).

Would this type of mecha be practical, or plausible at best?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a bit too broad of a question for you to get a good answer right now, and you might have better luck if you split into chunks, i.e. one question dealing with neural uploads, one for the robot itself, etc. You'll also have better result if you specify your limits, like the size of the robot, hard-science vs. soft science, that kind of thing.

Comment: Also, just to inform you, I took off the 'dyson-sphere' tag, because this question, as you've written it, has nothing to do with them.

Comment: It's not for us to determine if it's plausible in your world.  It's up to you to sell the plausibility to your audience. Note that asking if mechas are plausible in *this* world is off-topic. (Hint: they are not)

Comment: I agree with Halfthawed, this is best served by splitting up, and being asked in a way that makes it not opinion based

Comment: There's been a lot of conversation about this topic prevously. If you want to avoid having your question closed as duplicate, you'll want to read these threads completely and then follow up with whatever isn't covered there: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10320/plausible-reasons-for-usage-of-combat-mecha/99030 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30922/how-to-make-legged-fighting-vehicles-mecha-viable?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plausible Reasons for usage of Combat Mecha](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10320/plausible-reasons-for-usage-of-combat-mecha)

Answer (score 1):

**Plausible yes - Practical? Only if you deem it so.**

One of the problems with Mecha robots is that all their features are not optimised for their purpose.

Nearly every aspect of a super-sized humanoid Mecha robot is worse than a dedicated, more adequately and practically designed machine. Here are a few pointers:

- Walking: Why walk? We can fly now. There is limited usefulness in having 'two legged' robots because of stability, the fact you are stuck to the ground, the non-redundancy of it in case of mechanical failure, the awkwardness of movement.
- Sensory input: We evolved two eyes. In a way our mecha robots could be using extra sensors, but why not have a AWACS somewhere instead? Or coordinated effort with a swarm of drones. Putting all resources into one 'machine' is short-sighted (pun intended).
- Strategic usefulness: Given the lumbering, slow speed limitations of a mecha and the likely investment it requires, it is a struggle to imagine how one could be useful to a military, or even a scientific research effort. A submarine is good underwater, a drone for in the air. A Mecha is struggling for relevancy here.

Perhaps, as your question states regarding neural interfaces, the only possible advantage is that they are big versions of 'us', so is relatively intuitive to use without any training. Then it might be useful for those who might only want one or two minutes of training at most (as any longer and you could use a flying drone or a car...)

Comment: the power demand for walking is drastically less than for flight. there is a reason we use humvee and tanks instead of helicopters for everything.

Comment: @John if mecha like those described in the question or in general are possible to build, the power generation requirement for flying machines will have been long solved. Once you have your portable fusion core or handwavium-reactor, the energy costs of flying even something heavy aren't really a problem

Comment: @Dragongeek no its really not, portable fusion is not the same as zero weight fusion. in addition any power going to keeping you aloft is not going to other things, then you have the problem with recoil and aircraft.

Answer (score -1):

If you have unlimited material resources, you can build any structure of any shape in space, so long as it isn't heavy enough to create a substantial gravitational pull around its center.