# How would an armed bipedal mech stay standing up when moving around

Tags: engineering

Before you say this is a duplicate of [ceramicmrno0b’s post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/183231/how-to-keep-my-bipedal-mech-from-falling-over-on-its-side-every-time-it-takes-a), his is a much larger walker than mine is. Essentially, take an All Terrain Recon Transport I(AT-RT), add some side armor plates so the driver is (somewhat) cased in, and add side mounted weapons instead of front mounted ones. This mech is built for rapid movement and agility, instead of laying heavy fire. My mental image is about 2.5-3m tall and no more than a meter wide/deep (unless I add a tail). Would it be necessary for a tail/additional legs to keep it from falling over, or could  a gyroscope of some sort balance it?

Comment: Please include links when referencing other web resources. that is please provide a link for "ceramicmrno0b’s post"

Comment: What makes you think that the answers will be substantially different by virtue of asking about a different size?

Comment: (1) Most people on this site are not native English speakers, and I'm sad to confess that we may be unfamiliar with current slang. I have no idea what shameful five-letter word you have disguised by writing ar-rt. Atart? Atert? Atirt? Atort? Aturt? Atyrt? Cannot find any of them in the dictionary. (2) Ordinary humans are about 2 meters tall and we don't fall over when moving around. Why wouldn't the 3 meters tall *thing* be able to balance itself on its feet just like a human does?

Comment: I didn’t know if something large and potentially heavy like a gyroscope could fit on such a small mech.

Comment: @AlexP, its not slang, its an autocorrected abbreviation. It would say AT-RT, which is short for All Terrain Recon Transport. As for your second point, humans are soft, squishy and flexible. My mechs are made of metal and springs. They can’t lean, auto balance and/or have self adjusting foot placement like we do.

Comment: A human on stilts can be taller than your robot, with no articulation in the foot and can stand and balance just fine.

Comment: @sphennings, can that same human on a pair of stilts run across potentially rough terrain?

Comment: You may want to consider using the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) in the future, to get feedback on questions before asking them on the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spinning arms.**

https://youtu.be/fmxLyHQfpLA?t=38

[image]

Your mech has two swinging arms that spin in circles.  I think it would be best that they go in different directions.  This is a mech so instead of weights each arm can have a weighty weapon that it is spinning.

Like Bart spinning his arms on the way out of Lisa's room, if anything gets in the way of your mech and gets chopped, it is its own fault.

This is all to say I think your gyroscope idea is fine but not very mechy.   Having arms with medieval weapons serve that purpose mechs it up more I think.